# CGI.pm: file handle in global hash lost between subroutines?

Tags: perl, upload, cgi

I'd like to store file handle to a global hash and read() it in a subroutine without revealing CGI object, but I find that it doesn't work(resulting zero sized output file).

Here is the simplified perl code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI;
use vars qw(%in);

&init_hash;
$fname = &process_uploaded_file if($in{'upfile'});
$fsize = -s $fname;

print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n";
print "in{'upfile'}=",$in{'upfile'},"\r\n";
print "in{'desc'}=",$in{'desc'},"\r\n";
print "fname=",$fname,"\r\n";
print "fsize=",$fsize,"\r\n";

sub init_hash{
    my $q = new CGI;
    $in{'desc'} = $q->param('desc');
    $in{'upfile'} = $q->param('upfile');
    $in{'upfh'} = $q->upload('upfile') if($in{'upfile'});
}

sub process_uploaded_file{
    my $fname = time.'.bin';
    open(OUT,'>',$fname) || die('open file failed');
    while(my $read = read($in{'upfh'}, my $buff, 4096)){
        print OUT $buff;
    }
    close(OUT);
    eval { close($in{'upfh'}); };
    return $fname;
}
```

**EDIT:** I should provide perl and cgi.pm version.
Perl version: This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 2 (v5.12.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 8 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
$CGI::VERSION='3.50';

Comment: I think you need check whether the information is read from file $in{'upfh'}

Comment: @KostiaShiian but the file is created and writable. If I append the contents of process_uploaded_file to init_hash, and comment out line 7, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your code.

First your problem: you are trying to optimize where optimization isn't due. And the temp files of the CGI object are deleted before you actually access them. Your code should work when you extend the lifetime of the CGI object, e.g. by adding it to the `%in` hash.

---

- Always `use strict; use warnings;`. There are no excuses.
- Global variables are declared with `our`. The `vars` pragma is a historical artifact. But please don't use global variables, as they are unneccessary here.
- Don't call functions like `&foo` unless you can tell me what *exactly* this does. Until you have this knowledge: `foo()`.
- Use the `header` method of the CGI object to write headers: `$q->header('text/plain')`.
- The `\n` may not be what you think it is. Do a `binmode STDOUT` to remove the `:crlf` PerlIO-layer if it is currently applied. Although equivalent to `\r\n`, It may be clearer to write `\015\012` to demonstrate that you care about the actual bytes.
- You can interpolate variables into strings, you know. You can also specify a string that is to be appended after each `print` by setting `$\`:

  ```
  {
    local $\ = "\015\012";
    print "in{'upfile'}=$in{'upfile'}";
    print "in{'desc'}=$in{'desc'}";
    print "fname=$fname";
    print "fsize=$fsize";
  }
  ```
- Don't use bareword filehandles. Instead of `open OUT, "<", $fname` you should `open my $outfh, "<", $fname`.
- Why did you put one `close` in an `eval`? I don't see how this should `die`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding $q to %in does the trick. These code is legacy code(cca 2003) which runs well in old server.